# How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element in Golang?

Tags: html, templates, go, html-select

I want use a default value for a specific item in a list.
I tried the following code but I got an error of "*unexpected "=" in operand*
"
How can I handle this problem?

```
<select name="location_id">
    {{ range .LocationList}}
        <option value="{{ .Id }}" {{if .Name == .CurrentLocation}}selected{{end}}>{{ .Name }}</option>
    {{ end }} 
</select>
```

Comment: `{{if eq .Name .CurrentLocation}}`

Comment: Thanks a lot @MartinGallagher. It works well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality is implemented using Go templates using the `eq` function, to which you need to pass the arguments to compare. Specifically, the `if` function takes a *pipeline*, to which in this case you pass a function and a series of arguments. (See the docs for [actions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Actions) and [pipelines](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Pipelines).)

The correct syntax to use is:

```
{{ if eq <arg1> <arg2> }} ... {{ end }}
```

so, for your example:

```
{{ if eq .Name .CurrentLocation }} selected="selected"{{ end }}
```

(note attribute minimization is forbidden if you're using XHTML, so use `selected="selected"`, but for HTML, `selected` is permitted.)