# How to set default selected option to select tag with Golang?

Tags: go

First, I have found this question:

[How can I set the default value for an HTML <select> element in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457724/how-can-i-set-the-default-value-for-an-html-select-element-in-golang)

But in my case I don't know how to do.

I have many posts data and render them to template.

Controller:

```
c.Data["posts"] = posts_data
```

View:

```
{{ range $post := .posts }}
<option value="{{ $post.ID }}">{{ $post.Name }}</option>
{{ end }}
```

Works fine.

But if change to:

Controller:

```
c.Data["posts"] = posts_data
c.Data["post_id"] = param_data
```

View:

```
{{ range $post := .posts }}
<option value="{{ $post.ID }}" {{ if eq $post.ID .post_id }}selected="selected"{{ end }}>{{ $post.Name }}</option>
{{ end }}
```

Got error:

```
template Execute err: template: posts/index.tpl:20:70: executing "posts/index.tpl" at <.post_id>: can't evaluate field post_id in type models.Post
```

It's true that `post_id` doesn't exists in `models.Post`. But how to use it in this way?

Comment: The question is cross posted on [the reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/b8uqzu/how_to_set_default_selected_option_to_select_tag/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The range command sets `.` to the current value. Use `$` to refer to the root value passed to the template:

```
{{ range $post := .posts }}
<option value="{{ $post.ID }}" {{ if eq $post.ID $.post_id }}selected="selected"{{ end }}>{{ $post.Name }}</option>
{{ end }}
```

Because range sets `.`, the template can be simplified to:

```
{{ range $post := .posts }}
<option value="{{ .ID }}" {{ if eq .ID $.post_id }}selected="selected"{{ end }}>{{ .Name }}</option>
{{ end }}
```

Comment: Thank you. But got this error: `template: posts/index.tpl:20:70: executing "posts/index.tpl" at <eq $post.ID $.post...>: error calling eq: incompatible types for comparison`.

Comment: @seikyo_0402 Ensure that `c.Data["post_id"]` has the same type as post `ID` field.  Because the types are in code that you don't show, it's difficult to help more than this.